# Angular ngFor. Почему массив выводится в консоль несколько раз?

Tags: angular

Ксть код:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items()">some item</div>

items() {
    console.log(Array.from(Array(10).keys()));
    return Array.from(Array(10).keys());
}
```

Console.log почему-то выводит массив в консоли несколько раз.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lstpcw

Comment: Каждое обновление `View` вызывает функцию `items()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция items() будет вызыватся при каждом изменения компонента.
Лучше всего перенсти эту логику в ngOnInit

```
public items;

public ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(Array.from(Array(10).keys()));
    this.items = Array.from(Array(10).keys());
}
```